# simplexml is not returning children

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I am trying to parse the following XML but I cannot retrieve any children from the SimpleXML
The
WhateverItem is the first element and it contains a couple of children like whateverItem:Properties, whateverItem:Test etc.
Should the

```
$xmlDoc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
var_dump($xmlDoc->children());
```

return the children?

```
<whateverItem:item
 xmlns:prop="http://whatever.de/core/01/properties/" 
 xmlns:srel="http://whatever.de/core/01/structural-relations/" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   
 xml:base="http://mybasewhatever:8080"  
 xlink:type="simple" 
 xlink:title="My Item Title" 
 xlink:href="/ir/item/whatever:1220" 
 last-modification-date="2011-07-07T12:52:55.415Z" >

     <whateverItem:properties     
     xlink:type="simple" 
     xlink:title="Properties" 
     xlink:href="/ir/item/whatever:1220/properties">


    <prop:creation-date>2011-07-04T15:17:50.855Z</prop:creation-date>
    <srel:created-by  xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="System Administrator User" xlink:href="/aa/user-account/whatever:exuser1" />
    <prop:public-status>released</prop:public-status>


    <prop:version  xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="This Version" xlink:href="/ir/item/whatever:1220:4">
        <version:number >4</version:number>
        <version:date >2011-07-07T12:52:55.415Z</version:date>
        <version:status >released</version:status> 
         <srel:modified-by  xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="System Administrator User" xlink:href="/aa/user-account/whatever:exuser1" />
         <version:comment >Status changed to released for Item whatever:1220.</version:comment>
    </prop:version>

    <prop:latest-version  xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="Latest Version" xlink:href="/ir/item/whatever:1220:4">
        <version:number >4</version:number>
        <version:date >2011-07-07T12:52:55.415Z</version:date>
    </prop:latest-version>

    <prop:latest-release  xlink:type="simple" xlink:title="Latest public version" xlink:href="/ir/item/whatever:1220:4">
        <release:number >4</release:number>
        <release:date >2011-07-07T12:52:55.415Z</release:date>
    </prop:latest-release>
</whateverItem:properties>
...
<whateverItem:Test></whateverItem:Test>
</whateverItem:item>
```

Comment: My output is object(SimpleXMLElement)#392 (3) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["last-modification-date"]=>
    string(24) "2011-07-07T12:52:55.415Z"
  }
  ["properties"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#376 (0) {
  }
  ["Test"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#419 (0) {
  }
}

Comment: How strange, I just get the @attributes and nothing else!

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.1, Apache/2.2.14, DOM/XML  enabled,
DOM/XML API Version  20031129,
libxml Version  2.7.3,
HTML Support  enabled,
XPath Support  enabled,
XPointer Support  enabled,
Schema Support  enabled,
RelaxNG Support  enabled, libXML Loaded Version  20703,
libXML streams  enabled, Simplexml support enabled,
Revision  $Revision: 281953 $,
Schema support  enabled

Comment: Thank you Silex.
I assume there should be another problem. The xml code that I am using is a little bit larger and I did not put all the "childrens" in the code above. 
With the code above I was able to retrieve the same result. Thank you!
Looking to find a way to debug the error as the libxml_get_last_error() is not providing any information

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare the 'whateverItem' namespace in the actual XML input?  Try running your input through xmllint (a command-line utility in most Linux distros) to see if it picks up any problems, first.